# How to get the text which is outside of a element and changes in the run time using selenium c#?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver

I have piece of code as below

```
<div class="span6" style="text-align:right;">
    <span class="muted" style="padding-left:20px;">Member ID: </span>MKL123451KKM
    <span class="muted" style="padding-left:20px;">Service Date: </span>05/08/2018
</div>
```

in above code i want to get the value "**MKL123451KKM**", this value is going to change often.

i have tried with below xpaths which was giving error.

**XPATH** :

1. `/html/body/div/span[1][contains(text(),'Member ID:')]/../text()`
2. `/html/body/div/span[1][contains(.,'Member ID:')]/../text()`

**ERROR** :

The result of the xpath expression :

```
/html/body/div/span[1][contains(text(),'Member ID:')]/../text() is: [object Text]. It should be an element.
```

**NOTE:**

i am using selenium driver for IE and c# with VS 2015 IDE

Can anybody throw light on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were fairly close. It's generally not a good practice to create a locator that starts at the HTML tag or has too many levels because it's more brittle (more likely to break when the page changes). Ideally you would find the label element by text label, e.g. "Member ID", and then locate the following text node. The big benefit of this method is that it's tied to the "Member ID" label. Some of the other answers are hard-coded to a specific text node which may be good now but if the data changes, it may return the wrong value.

You can wrap this all in a function where you pass in the label and it returns the value.

```
public string GetValue(string labelName)
{
    IWebElement e = Driver.FindElement(By.XPath($"//span[contains(.,'{labelName}')]"));
    string s = (string)((IJavaScriptExecutor)Driver).ExecuteScript("return arguments[0].nextSibling.textContent;", e);
    return s.Trim();
}
```

and you would call it like

```
GetValue("Member ID")
```

Comment: Can you share any useful link about text node and execute script statements like `arguments[0].nextSibling.textContent;` , that would be really helpful. Thanks

Comment: @cruisepandey I would recommend looking all of this up on MDN. I think their documentation is some of the best. They've also got stuff on XPath, etc. See [.nextSibling()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nextSibling) and [.textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent). It's basically all JS calls... you just need to know the JS API around dealing with elements. The MDN articles and others will help there.

Comment: Surly , I would definitely have a look. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

As per the HTML you have shared the text **MKL123451KKM** is not within any child `<span>` node but within the parent `<div>` node. To extract the text e.g. **MKL123451KKM** you can use the following code block :

```
IWebElement elem = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@class='span6']"));
string text = (string)((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("return arguments[0].childNodes[2].textContent;", elem);
```

Comment: This is one of the good way to find text which are outside of inner tag and still present in Outer tags. (+1)

Comment: @cruisepandey This answer is hardcoded to a particular node. If the data changes, it will return the wrong value. There is a more flexible way to do this...

Answer (score 0):

That's because the text is within the div. You will need to get text from xpath:

```
//div[@class='span6']
```

Even though this xpath isn't very change-proof, it should work if you get text from it. The text though will be MKL123451KKM and 05/08/2018

Answer (score 0):

Try this XPath

```
//div[@class='span6']/span/following-sibling::text()[1]
```